# iPhoneOS SDK - Remove Corner Rounding from views (iPad problem)

Tags: iphone, ipad, rounded-corners, uisplitviewcontroller

This might be a little bit picky, but in the iPad SplitViewController setup, there are 2 views. Each of the views has a very small black corner rounding. (This is probably the same with iPhone apps too).

This rounding is visible in the image below. What I would like to do is remove the black rounding, so the UI doesnt get these two little bumps along the bottom. Has anyone done this, or know how to? -Its surely possible.

Hopefully some one has seen this before.

Thanks

[Image Link Mirror](http://norskben.posterous.com/this-might-be-picky-but-i-want-to-remove-the)

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/7297/screenshot20100413at102.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/7297/screenshot20100413at102.png)

Comment: Is this at the bottom of a window? It might actually be done via clipping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following to your app delegate:

```
- (void) fixRoundedSplitViewCorner
{
    [self explode:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] level:0];
}

- (void) explode:(id)aView level:(int)level
{
 if ([aView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
  UIImageView* roundedCornerImage = (UIImageView*)aView;
  roundedCornerImage.hidden = YES;
 }
 if (level < 2) {
  for (UIView *subview in [aView subviews]) {
   [self explode:subview level:(level + 1)];
  }
 }
}
```

In your DetailViewController of the UISplitViewController add:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
 [yourAppDelegate performSelector:@selector(fixRoundedSplitViewCorner) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks to be the go! Fantastic Thanks. The code only executes when I press a tablecell in the MasterViewController, or i guess until DetailViewController is refreshed. I have tried calling fixRoundedSplitViewCorner from every viewDidLoad but I cant get it to work on first load. Can you give the last piece of the puzzle to?

The above code is fantastic so far!

Comment: You only need to call fixRoundedSplitViewCorner when the device gets rotated. Add the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation as posted above and it will work on application launch too.

Comment: Doesn't appear to do anything for me (iOS5).

Comment: Don't forget to check if didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is actually called.  The code does work on iOS 5 and above.

Comment: It works, but caused me some issues where the UI would lockup if device was rotated 180 degrees. from landscape to reverse landscape for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to override `drawRect` in the view and draw your it yourself without the rounding.