# How to remove rounded corners from UINavigationBar and UIToolbar with custom background images?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar, rounded-corners

In a split-view-based iPad app I'm using a custom background image in my navigation bars and toolbars.
I subclassed `UINavigationBar` and/or `UIToolbar` and in `drawRect:` I have (*background-image* is rectangular):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-image"];    

    CGContextDrawImage(c, rect, image.CGImage);
}
```

Result is 
[image: Rounded corners]
from which I want to remove rounded corners.

What I've tried already:

1. `[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];` the same result as above,
2. `clipsToBounds = YES;` in my subclasses,
3. `cornerRadius=0.0`,
4. [iPhoneOS SDK - Remove Corner Rounding from views (iPad problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628080/iphoneos-sdk-remove-corner-rounding-from-views-ipad-problem)

Problem described in 4. is exactly the same one I'm having. Unfortunately solution described in that question doesn't work for me. When called from `viewWillAppear` In Portrait orientation, it hides my navigationItem for some reason. When called from `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` in Landscape, rounded corners are gone, but at the same time all user interaction is disabled. Additionaly, when rotated back to Portrait, my "Master" view (left hand-side of the split view) is not hidden.

The output that I got using the code from the accepted answer is:

```
aView: <UIWindow: 0x5e18470; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5e18280>>
subview: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x6942000; frame = (20 0; 748 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6946b30>>
aView: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x6942000; frame = (20 0; 748 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6946b30>>
subview: <BackgroundImageView: 0xbbacf70; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); layer = <CALayer: 0xbbad020>>
aView: <BackgroundImageView: 0xbbacf70; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); layer = <CALayer: 0xbbad020>>
subview: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x69144e0; frame = (321 0; 703 748); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x6946fe0>>
aView: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x69144e0; frame = (321 0; 703 748); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x6946fe0>>
subview: <UILayoutContainerView: 0xbbabc40; frame = (0 0; 320 748); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xbbabc90>>
aView: <UILayoutContainerView: 0xbbabc40; frame = (0 0; 320 748); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xbbabc90>>
subview: <UIImageView: 0x5e178c0; frame = (321 0; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba60d10>> - (null)
aView: <UIImageView: 0x5e178c0; frame = (321 0; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba60d10>> - (null)
subview: <UIImageView: 0xba74010; frame = (317 0; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba62180>> - (null)
aView: <UIImageView: 0xba74010; frame = (317 0; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba62180>> - (null)
subview: <UIImageView: 0xbad0110; frame = (321 745; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba60da0>> - (null)
aView: <UIImageView: 0xbad0110; frame = (321 745; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba60da0>> - (null)
subview: <UIImageView: 0xba60e00; frame = (317 745; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba60e30>> - (null)
aView: <UIImageView: 0xba60e00; frame = (317 745; 3 3); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xba60e30>> - (null)
```

And quite right there are small, 3x3px, rounded UIImageViews with corners.

**Question is**: how do I get rid of those tiny rounded corners?

Comment: Any luck with this? Running across this same issue myself currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

```
- (void)hideSplitViewCorners {
// Hide corners of splitview.
NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray array];
[views addObject:[self view]];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < views.count; ++i) {
    UIView *view = [views objectAtIndex:i];
    [views addObjectsFromArray:view.subviews];

    if (view.frame.size.width == 3.0 && view.frame.size.height == 3.0) {
        view.hidden = YES;
    }
  }    
}
```

I call it in `loadView` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` of my subclass of `UISplitViewController`.
Note that in the latter I needed to use `[self performSelector:@selector(hideSplitViewCorners) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0];`.

Basically, one needs to make sure that hiding of those corners are done **after** they're already displayed on the screen.