# Remove separator on UISplitviewcontroller

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

I´m using a UISplitViewController.  Just a simple question.
Is it possible to remove the black separator when ViewController is in Landscape mode?

http://img809.imageshack.us/i/skrmavbild20110204kl.png/

Regards!
/ M

Comment: There is possible to set the devider color. For example: [[splitView view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]; BUT, this will give us a line that is the same height as View itself. And it will still leave a black separator thingy at the bottom.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589890/uisplitviewcontroller-remove-divider-line/7575078#7575078

Enjoy!!!