# Single title bar for split views

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uistoryboard

I need to design a screen similar to below screen.[image: split view search results]
The screen has a split view but shares a common title bar. Can this be done using split view controllers in storyboard? Or do we need to add the master & detail views in storyboard and manage their content from viewcontroller implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Ashawini, obviously they have used a single view controller containing subviews which have a layout to look like split view controller. There is no way to extend the UINavigationBar in the split view controller like in the image above, because both master and detail have separate bars.

EDIT: 
This was already asked before. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981588/750431