# Delete line between RootView(master) and DetailView(detail) in 'Status bar'

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, statusbar

My app uses UISplitViewController (Master-Detail template),
And there is 'line' between RootView(master) and Detail(detail) in  'Status bar'.

Any one has a idea why this line exist, and how to delete it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589890/uisplitviewcontroller-remove-divider-line...

Comment: iAnurag : Thanks ! I got it. Someone having same problem, check the article above.